# Setting jsp checkbox with a value from database

Tags: java, jsp

Ok. I'm making a java web app with a database backend to do some CRUD on some data. When the edit button is clicked next to an item, it navigates to a form with the current data for editing. One of the fields is boolean and I would like to display it as a checkbox so that `True` makes it checked and `False` leaves it unchecked.

I have tried many different variations none seem to work. Here are some examples where `<%= action.get("stable")%>` returns a string with either `True` or `False`

```
<input TYPE=checkbox name="stable" value=<%= action.get("stable") %>

<input TYPE=checkbox name="stable" value=<%= action.get("stable")?"True":"False" %><%= action.get("stable")?"checked":"" %>

<input TYPE=checkbox name="stable" checked=<%= action.get("stable")%>/>
```

So how do you set a check box to checked/unchecked depending on the string returned with `action.get("stable")`

Thank you for any help sorry if the question is a bit trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct markup for a checked checkbox is `checked="checked"`. If it's not checked, the `checked` attribute must not be present at all.

You should generate it using the JSTL and the JSP EL, because scriptlets are something from the past which should not be used in JSPs for years. See [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

This would of course need some refactoring so that the action bean has a regular `isStable()` method returning a boolean, which would be much cleaner. But anyway, here's how it would work using your existing code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stable" <% 
    if ("True".equals(action.get("stable"))) {
        out.print("checked=\"checked\"");
    } %>/>
```

Note that all attributes should also be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: thank you i agree i'm not to sure why we are required to do scriptlets when it is not used any more. Anyway i appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: Why would you be required to do scriptlets? Is it homework where the teacher forces you to use scriptlets? If so, then kindly tell your teacher that he should change his lessons. If not, then don't use them. Use the EL, the JSTL and custom tags.

Comment: yes im working on a project for tafe. This is the first web based ap we got so i think maybe the next one will be more up to date. I will ask him Monday tho =]

Comment: With JSTL: `<c:if test="${stable eq true}">checked=checked</c:if>` assuming there is a request parameters with the key 'stable'.

Comment: @hisdrewness: this would need the stable request param to be a boolean. And it would be better written as `<c:if test="${stable}">checked="checked"</c:if>`

Answer (score 5):

I used this, and it worked perfectly.

```
 <input type="checkbox" <c:if test="${item.estado==2}">checked=checked</c:if> class="switch-input" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `checked` attribute of `<input type="checkbox"/>`

Edit:

```
<input type="checkbox" <%=action.get("stable") ? "checked='checked'" : "" %> />
```

Comment: Yeh the third example above is. So its setting it to True or False but in both instances it is setting the checkbox as checked

Comment: @zac - you have to add checked="checked".